# How to get features from WFS as a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, wfs, getfeature, owslib

I have a WFS running on URL that is mentioned in the code below. i want to get all the features available in the service as a shapefile so i can open it and visualize it in QGIS or any other GIS software. The servies provides the ability to download the shapefile as can be viewed here :

https://www.geoseaportal.de/wss/service/Site_Development_Plan_2020/guest?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0

I have tried the below code to fetch the data and save as a shapefile but it just creates an empty point shapefile which is not correct. How can i download it correctly?

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

eaWFS = WebFeatureService(url='https://www.geoseaportal.de/wss/service/Site_Development_Plan_2020/guest?SERVICE=WFS', version='2.0.0')

floodData = eaWFS.getfeature(typename='Site_Development_Plan_2020:All', bbox=(419000,419000,421000,421000), outputFormat='SHAPE-ZIP')

out = open('C:\\Users\Chaudhr1\\arcgis\DATA.zip', 'wb')
out.write(floodData.read())
out.close()
```

Comment: Does the url work in your browser?

Comment: I am going to assume that you are using the same code from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411376/wfs-layer-saved-as-a-shapefile) and you didn't change your `bbox` values?

Comment: This WFS opens easily in QGIS, and Export >> Save Features As... works. Why are you using code?

Comment: @IanTurton yes it does

Comment: @Binks yes i did not. but i constructed url manually for get feataures and was able to download the zip shapefile but i dont know how to do the same with pytthon

Comment: @Pointdump i actually want to work in jupyter notebooks and dont want to use any software for visualization. that is just for testing  that i want to store it as a sapefile and then see if the data is correctly downaloded

Answer (score 5):

As @Binks alludes to in their comment, your bounding box is incorrect for the data you are querying. This runs in the Python console of QGIS, but you can copy-paste the printed `bbox` tuple into your Jupyter Notebook.

```py
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

# add WFS to QGIS and get the extent
ext = iface.activeLayer().extent()  

# construct a bbox tuple from the extent
bbox = (ext.xMinimum(), ext.yMinimum(), ext.xMaximum(), ext.yMaximum())

print(bbox)
# (3905180.8005, 3416324.4063, 4611648.3389, 3649276.3886)

eaWFS = WebFeatureService(url='https://www.geoseaportal.de/wss/service/Site_Development_Plan_2020/guest?SERVICE=WFS', version='2.0.0')

floodData = eaWFS.getfeature(typename='Site_Development_Plan_2020:All', bbox=bbox, outputFormat='SHAPE-ZIP')

out = open(r'C:\\Users\Chaudhr1\\arcgis\DATA.zip', 'wb')
out.write(floodData.read())
out.close()
```

[image]

Comment: alright. so thats the issue. i just have one additional question. so when i try to sepcify "srsname" in "getfeature" like `srsname='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3035'`, it give me error `unexpected keyword argument. could you please update your code on how to specify the crs as well while fetching the features?