# Invalid keyword argument when specify coordinate system for a WFS GetFeature

Tags: wfs, getfeature, owslib

I am trying to get features from a WFS in the form of a shapefile using OWSlib package in Python. I am able to download the shapefile as a zip but when I specify the coordinate system while defining `getfeatures` method, it gives me error that `srsname is an invalid keyword argument`.

How can I fix this?

This question is a continuation of the question in link below. The code and related previous discussion is there:

[How to get features from WFS as a shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427522/how-to-get-features-from-wfs-as-a-shapefile/427538#427538)

Comment: Please write your code with srsname into this question instead of linking to a comment in another question.

Comment: Where in your code are you specifying `srsname`   Are you matching  the correct epsg code per WFS version requested  `urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3035`  for version 1.1.0 `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3035` for version 2.  Note though as the service only supports one projection you don't need to specify one